# Swift 3 Generic fetch request extension

Tags: swift, swift3

I implemented an extension for the `NSManagedObjectContext` that takes any CoreData class as a parameter and performs a fetch request on it.

I am new to CoreData and would very much appreciate any sort of feedback for this function

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext{
func fetchObjects <T: NSManagedObject>(_ entityClass:T.Type, sortBy: [NSSortDescriptor]? = nil, predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) throws -> [AnyObject]{
    var request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        request = entityClass.fetchRequest()
    } else {
        let entityClassName = NSStringFromClass(entityClass)
        let entityName = entityClassName.components(separatedBy: ".").last ?? entityClassName
        request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
    }

    var fetchRequestError: Error?
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    if let predicate = predicate {
        request.predicate = predicate
    }
    if let sortBy = sortBy {
        request.sortDescriptors = sortBy
    }

    var fetchedResult: [T]?

        do {
            fetchedResult = try self.fetch(request) as? [T]
        }
        catch let error {
            fetchRequestError = error
            //print(fetchRequestError)
        }

    guard let entityArray = fetchedResult else {
        throw fetchRequestError!
    }

    return entityArray
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code looks good, but there are some things which can be simplified.
Additionally, the method can be improved to return a array of the
actual managed object subclass type instead of `AnyObject`.

#### Simplifications and small improvements

> ```
> var request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>
> ```

`request` is assigned exactly once, therefore it should be a *constant:*

---

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>
```

> ```
> let entityClassName = NSStringFromClass(entityClass)
> let entityName = entityClassName.components(separatedBy: ".").last ?? entityClassName
> ```

can be simplified to

```
let entityName = String(describing: entityClass)
```

which returns the unqualified class name of the given class
(in contrast to `String(reflecting:)` which returns the fully qualified
class name including the module name).

---

> ```
> if let predicate = predicate {
>     request.predicate = predicate
> }
> if let sortBy = sortBy {
>     request.sortDescriptors = sortBy
> }
> ```

The `predicate` and `sortDescriptors` of `NSFetchRequest` *are optionals,* so there is no need to conditionally unwrap 
the given parameters. You can assign them directly:

```
request.predicate = predicate
request.sortDescriptors = sortBy
```

---

> ```
> fetchedResult = try self.fetch(request) as? [T]
> ```

We *know* that the fetch request returns an array of `T` objects,
the cast cannot fail. Therefore the second half of the method
can be reduced to

```
do {
    let fetchedResult = try self.fetch(request) as! [T]
    return fetchedResult
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    throw error
}
```

making the `fetchRequestError` variable obsolete. And if you don't
need to print the error locally then no do/catch is needed at all:

```
let fetchedResult = try self.fetch(request) as! [T]
return fetchedResult
```

A possible error will be re-thrown to the caller of the method.

---

Putting it all together, the method now looks like this:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext{
    func fetchObjects <T: NSManagedObject>(_ entityClass:T.Type,
                       sortBy: [NSSortDescriptor]? = nil,
                       predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) throws -> [AnyObject] {

        let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            request = entityClass.fetchRequest()
        } else {
            let entityName = String(describing: entityClass)
            request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
        }

        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        request.predicate = predicate
        request.sortDescriptors = sortBy

        let fetchedResult = try self.fetch(request) as! [T]
        return fetchedResult
    }
}
```

---

#### Returning a "correctly" typed array

The return type is `[AnyObject]`, which means that the return value has to be cast to the actual managed object subclass type

```
let objects = try context.fetchObjects(YourEntity.self) as! [YourEntity]
```

This can be improved by changing the return type to `[T]` and using
a typed fetched request `NSFetchRequest<T>`:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext{
    func fetchObjects <T: NSManagedObject>(_ entityClass:T.Type,
                       sortBy: [NSSortDescriptor]? = nil,
                       predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) throws -> [T] {

        let request: NSFetchRequest<T>
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            request = entityClass.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<T>
        } else {
            let entityName = String(describing: entityClass)
            request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
        }

        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        request.predicate = predicate
        request.sortDescriptors = sortBy

        let fetchedResult = try self.fetch(request)
        return fetchedResult
    }
}
```

This is now called as

```
let objects = try context.fetchObjects(YourEntity.self)
```

and `objects` is an array of `YourEntity` without additional cast.

Answer (score 0):

It looks solid to me, but I can't comment on performance-wise. My issue was trying to read it. It took me a few minutes of figuring it out before I had to reformat it in Xcode:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {

    func fetchObjects <T: NSManagedObject>(_ entityClass: T.Type,
                                             sortBy: [NSSortDescriptor]? = nil,
                                             predicate: NSPredicate? = nil)
     throws -> [AnyObject] {

        var request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            request = entityClass.fetchRequest()
        } else {
            let entityClassName = NSStringFromClass(entityClass)
            let entityName = entityClassName.components(separatedBy: ".").last
                             ?? entityClassName

            request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
        }

        var fetchRequestError: Error?
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        if let predicate = predicate {
            request.predicate = predicate
        }

        if let sortBy = sortBy {
            request.sortDescriptors = sortBy
        }

        var fetchedResult: [T]?

        do {
            fetchedResult = try self.fetch(request) as? [T]
        }
        catch let error {
            fetchRequestError = error
            //print(fetchRequestError)
        }

        guard let entityArray = fetchedResult else {
            throw fetchRequestError!
        }

        return entityArray
    }
}
```

I know your style is definitely different from mine, ( I would wrap each thing up in a labeled do block, or comment each section based on its purpose) but I think that mine is considerably easier to read, and I tried to respect your coding style and the Swift conventions.

A couple places you had inconsistent spacing and linebreaks

My two biggest issues were the single line func declaration, and your nil coalesce.. I didn't realize until after I'd reformatted that you had actually assigned a value to `request` after that (it all looked like one line to me)

Just my 2c.. I know I tend to over-linebreak in my code, but for me, it took me a while to figure out what was going on in your code initially. A few extra breaks can help emphasize when you are starting a new logic sequence, or when you are setting one one up vs actually defining it.

Overall an "A" I think! :D Not that mine is any better. Just my take on it.

Hope this helps.

---

PS, here is my personal rendition of it:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {

    func fetchObjects<T: NSManagedObject> (_ entityClass: T.Type,
                                             sortBy:      [NSSortDescriptor]? = nil,
                                             predicate:   NSPredicate?        = nil)
     throws -> [AnyObject] {

        // Initial request:
        var request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            request = entityClass.fetchRequest()
        }

        else {
            let entityClassName = NSStringFromClass(entityClass)
            let entityName = entityClassName.components(separatedBy: ".").last
                                             ?? entityClassName

            request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
        }

        // Fetch request:
        var fetchRequestError: Error?
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        if let predicate = predicate { request.predicate = predicate }
        if let sortBy = sortBy { request.sortDescriptors = sortBy }

        var fetchedResult: [T]?

        do { fetchedResult = try self.fetch(request) as? [T] }
        catch let error { fetchRequestError = error }

        // Returner:
        guard let entityArray = fetchedResult
            else { throw fetchRequestError! }

        return entityArray
    }
}
```